# Android Managment API Command Timeout Problem

Tags: android-management-api, android-enterprise, android-enterprise-features

When the "Duration" in https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/issueCommand expires, no Time Out information comes from Pub/Sub. At the same time, when we query the command, there is no information that the command will no longer go. Can we perceive this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is not  supported yet. Currently, Pub/Sub can display commands that are successfully submitted and commands that return errors.

There is an existing feature request for this but there is no guarantee when this will be worked on. To stay up to date with the latest updates for Android enterprise, we suggest that you [join the Android Management API mailing list](https://developers.google.com/android/management/release-notes) to receive monthly updates and service advisories directly to your inbox.